# How does ORACLE database convert DATE to NUMBER implicitly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to understand this function:

```
NVL2( NULL, ( SYSDATE - SYSDATE ), DATE '2020-05-24' ))
```

And its returned value:

```
NVL2(NULL,(SYSDATE-SYSDATE),DATE '2020-05-24'))

2458994
```

I'm having trouble understanding where that number, `2458994`, comes from, as `SYSDATE-SYSDATE` is a `NUMBER`, and you cannot *implicity* convert a `DATE` to a `NUMBER`:

```
TO_NUMBER(DATE '2020-05-24')
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

The [ORACLE SQL Language Reference NVL2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NVL2.html#GUID-414D6E81-9627-4163-8AC2-BD24E57742AE) states:

> If expr2 is numeric data, then Oracle Database determines which argument has the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the other argument to that data type, and returns that data type.

So my question is, what form of conversion is ORACLE SQL using on the `DATE` datatype to make it a `NUMBER` datatype?

Answer (score 6):

It's effectively doing:

```
to_number(to_char(DATE '2020-05-24','J'))
```

The 'J' is ([from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A)):

> Julian day; the number of days since January 1, 4712 BC. Number specified with J must be integers.

If you run that manually it gets the same value you see:

```
select to_number(to_char(DATE '2020-05-24','J')) from dual;

2458994
```

It isn't obvious that it *should* be doing that, but it is. If the second argument is a plain (type-2) number then you get an error:

```
select NVL2(NULL,42,to_date('2020-05-24','YYYY-MM-DD')) from dual;

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

If you dump the date subtraction result it comes back as a different (internal, undocumented as far as I can see) data type:

```
select dump(SYSDATE-SYSDATE) from dual;

Typ=14 Len=8: 114,133,37,0,0,0,0,0
```

That seems to cause the third argument to be converted to that same type; it's *almost* equivalent to:

```
select DATE '2020-05-24' - DATE '-4712-01-01' from dual;

2458993
```

So it looks like it's either doing something similar to that but adjusting it, or doing an internal version of the 'J' conversion, or... something else vaguely similar. It doesn't seem to be documented behaviour.

Comment: The way Oracle converts to Julian Day, seems to be an internal storage conversion, and it is how oracle stores dates used in arithmetic, so it's makes sense that the DATE datatype is compatible, and like you mentioned it is not obvious.  However, I'm still lost with why its undocumented.

Comment: Thank you, for your help.  All the material I found was byte to the number of days conversion through the dump() function. If interested here's the link (PS. its math..) : https://bennytu.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/subtracting-dates-in-oracle-how-it-is-stored-internally/